# Sorting Array in TypeScript (Ionic)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to sort my array by id. However, when I use the sort() method nothing happens.

```
products.sort(function (a, b) {
  return a.id - b.id;
});
```

How can I fix this?

My attempt:

```
constructor(private pokemonService: PokemonService, private typeColorFactory: TypeColorFactoryService, private screenOrientation: ScreenOrientation) {
    this.pokemonService.getPokemons(1).subscribe(
      res => {
        console.log(res);

        this.pokemons = res;
        this.pokemons.sort((a, b): Pokemon => {
          if (a.id < b.id) return -1;
          if (a.id > b.id) return 1;
          return 0;
        });
        console.log(this.pokemons);
      },
      err => {
        console.log('HTTP Error', err);
      }
    );
  }
```

The array always stays the same! I don't know if it matters, but when I `console.log()` within the sort, it doesn't log anything (don't know if that is possible though).

Model:

> pastebin.com/FLTiZPSA

Data:

> [image: data]

**UPDATE:**

```
const products=[
  {'id':'1','name':'A'},
  {'id':'3','name':'C'},
  {'id':'4','name':'D'},
  {'id':'2','name':'B'},
];
products.sort((a,b)=> {
  console.log("test");
  return a.id-b.id;
});
this.pokemons.sort((a,b) => {
  console.log("test");
  return a.id-b.id;
});
```

products.sort() DOES log "test".

this.pokemons.sort() DOES NOT log "test".

Link to this.pokemonService: https://pastebin.com/raWJ9isP

Comment: nope, didn't help :( I've updated the post.

Comment: Can you show your data?

Comment: Your TypeScript is not well formed; it should be `sort((a: Pokemon, b: Pokemon) => {`

Comment: I've tried  sort((a: Pokemon, b: Pokemon) => { , unfortunately it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: are your sure your pokemons have the `id` property and that it's spelled correctly?

Comment: You should be able to log in the compare function you provide for sorting. Try logging it there. Try it before `return a.id - b.id;`. Let us know what it prints.

Comment: @sudobangbang like already mentioned in the question, nothing prints when I add it. I even tried to toast something.

Comment: @Frogical, where are you putting the log though? I don't understand what you mean by "toast something"

Comment: @sudobangbang this.pokemons = this.pokemons.sort((a: Pokemon,b: Pokemon)=> {
          console.log("test");
          return a.id-b.id;}
        );

Comment: this happened to me today, this.pokemons doesn't have the data yet so you need to wait for the data to be appended to this.pokemons before you sort it out.

Answer (score 0):

Following should work :

```
const products=[
  {'id':'1','name':'A'},
  {'id':'3','name':'C'},
  {'id':'4','name':'D'},
  {'id':'2','name':'B'},
];

console.log(products);

products.sort((a,b)=> a.id-b.id);

console.log(products);
```

This Results in sorted array:

```
[[object Object] {
  id: "1",
  name: "A"
}, [object Object] {
  id: "2",
  name: "B"
}, [object Object] {
  id: "3",
  name: "C"
}, [object Object] {
  id: "4",
  name: "D"
}]
```

Comment: Yeah, that does work! However when I apply this to my own object (this.pokemons), it doesn't work! I don't understand why. And a sidenote, when I log your array before and after the sort. They are both sorted, even if the array is initialised as unsorted.

Comment: They are not both sorted, it's just that your browser shows the new data in the older console.log

Comment: Okey, thanks for the explanation. Do you know why it doesn't work for my array (see model: https://pastebin.com/FLTiZPSA)?

Comment: Here i want to add few points to crosscheck :
1) since you are copying response by reference this.pokemons = res; , are you modifying "res"" object or anywhere you have assigned this.pokemons by reference, in that case it will take the value of the lastest "res" by reference.
2) you have to deepCopy your variable in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Now try to this.

```
this.lstClients = this.lstClients.sort(function (a, b) {
              if (a.id < b.id) { return -1; }
              if (a.id > b.id) { return 1; }
              return 0;
});
```

Comment: Tried it, is not the solution unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

In cmd/terminal run this commands:

```
1. install npm install ngx-sortable app.module.ts import
2. import { NgxSortableModule } from 'ngx-sortable'
3. @NgModule({
  imports: [
    ...,
    NgxSortableModule
  ],
  ...
})
```

then in your html code for grid table write shown as below:

```
<ion-col data-column="id" (click)="SortData('id')" [ngClass]="{'asc': sortColumn == 'id' && sortOrder == 'asc', 'desc': sortColumn == 'id' && sortOrder == 'asc'}">
enter code here
```

`In .ts file`

```
sortOrder: string = 'asc';
  sortColumn = 'eq_id';
  
  constructor() {}

    SortData(col: string): void {
    if (this.sortColumn == col) {
      if (this.sortOrder == 'asc')
        this.sortOrder = 'desc';
      else
        this.sortOrder = 'asc';
    }
    else {
      this.sortColumn = col;
      this.sortOrder = 'asc';
    }
    this.Location = this.Location.sort((a, b) => {
      if (a[col] < b[col]){
        return this.sortOrder == 'asc' ? 1 : -1;
      }
      if (a[col] > b[col])
      {
        return this.sortOrder == 'asc' ? -1 : 1;
      }
      return 0;
    })
  }
```